# Java "Iterator" keyword

Tags: java, iterator, queue

I was asked in my exam to write an algorithm on queues in Java. I used an `Iterator` to extract the elements of the queue. (The elements consisted of chars : `'R'` or `'W'` or `'B'` ONLY ). The question prohibited creating or destroying any character of the input queue. I just wanted to ask whether using `Iterator` to extract elements "creates" characters or not? 
My algorithm was:

```
Q=Queue
Iterator dummy=Q.elements();
while (//some condition){
   if (dummy.data=='R')
   ...
   ...
```

This is just the algorithm. I wanted to ask whether I've "created" elements or not because I was awarded `0` marks for it. :(

Comment: `Iterator` is not a keyword in java. Check interface [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: @Nandkumar: Okay. I've edited my question. Keeping aside whether it's a keyword or not..does it create new elements? I've written my algorithm in the question.

Comment: @user188995: Have you seen the javadoc that Nandkumar posted? Perhaps you would know why you got a 0 for your answer (*hint, it has nothing to do with "creating" or "destroying" but more so with how you've written your code*)

Comment: @Sujay: The above code is only an **algorithm**. I just wanted to ask whether use of "Iterator" will create any duplicate/or any new elements or not. 
What I think is that Iterator provides a way of going in a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method on queue like `elements()` it is `element()` which `Retrieves but does not remove element from the queue` the correct method is `queue.iterator()`;

Any way logically you are some what correct and you didn't deserve `0`

You can access using `new for loop` also

```
    for(Object object : queue) {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: I just want to ask that whether I created new elements or not using Iterator?

Comment: Answer is no you don't have any method to assign value to `iterator` like this. It only allows you to read and which does not create any object.

Comment: Thanks. My logic was simple using an "Iterator" in the "literal sense". Not in a programming-word. We had to write algorithm in **plain English**. So, my idea was to start from `0 to n` and read each `char` of Queue. So are you sure that I've not "created" any new or duplicate elements?

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is a value type, so all assignments result in a "copy" being made.

Answer (score 0):

No, iterator does not create anything.  Characters in java are objects, immutable and passed by reference out of array ( and to keep  memory usage down they are reused  behind the scenes ):

```
 public static Character valueOf(char c) {
    if(c <= 127) { // must cache
        return CharacterCache.cache[(int)c];
    }
        return new Character(c);
    }
```

Comment: Iterator will provide boxed types  - also objects

Comment: So a copy _is_ created, since the `chars` are boxed (the cache starts empty).

Comment: but only once, and before you put them in the queue